# Spring: Specifying cron property in @Scheduled from an SPEL expression in Spring 4.1.3

Tags: spring, spring-batch, scheduling, spring-el, spring-scheduled

Consider the following code:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "#{@returnCron}")
public void foo(){
    someJob.do();
}

@Bean
public String returnCron(){
    return "0 /5 * * * *"; // ideally, from the properties file or system variable
}
```

In **Spring 4.1.3** which I'm using, the [`Scheduled`](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--) annotation doesn't seem to support placeholders for the `cron` attribute (I'm assuming that's why an error is coming). In the [current version](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html#cron--) though, the doc states that it supports placeholders.

How can I make `SPEL` work in the `cron` attribute in **Spring 4.1.3**? In general, how to externalize the `cron` expression when placeholders are not supported?

My error is:

```
Cron expression must consist of 6 fields (found 1 in "#{@returnCron}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Still `*/5` is same as `/5`, it works with `0 */5 * * * *`. Please try :

Properties file :

```
cronExpression=0 */5 * * * *
```

Scheduled method :

```
@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Scheduled(cron = "${cronExpression}")
    private void testSchedule() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: My question was with respect to using SpEL inside the cron attribute, and how can we use it when placeholders are not supported in the version I'm using (Spring 4.1.3)